# expected string got property instead

Tags: python, dynamic, properties, pycharm, typing

Code snippet:

```
def copy_additional_files(self):
try:
    for filetocopy in self.files_to_copy:
        shutil.copy2(FileToCopy.get_source, FileToCopy.get_target)
except NotImplementedError:
    logging.error('keep thinking')
    raise EwaException
```

`get_source` is a `@property` that returns a string - `shutil.copy2` needs a string to work

My IDE (PyCharm 4.0.6) tells me that it expected a string but got a property instead.

Is that a bug? A property can return a string and so `additional_file_source` can be a string as well (as it is intended to be), but it returns the object ID of the property object when i print it:

```
<property object at 0x....> <property object at 0x....>
```

and throws:

> 'Property' does not support buffer interface

Is there a more simple and obvious way to do this without an error?

Comment: Ignore what PyCharm says. Does the code work?

Comment: You get a warning or an actual error?

Comment: it returns the object id of the properties; so I ve got a new question: How do i assign the return value to the var name

Comment: It is telling you that you are trying to use a  `Property` object not a string. i.e a  Property class object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling the property on the class itself, rather than on the instance of the class that you get inside the loop. It should be:

```
for filetocopy in self.files_to_copy:
    shutil.copy2(filetocopy.get_source, filetocopy.get_target)
```

(Also, please choose better names; `get_source` implies a method that you call, the property should just be `source`.)